# Why does Struts 2 depend on springframework?

Tags: java, spring, maven, struts2, dependencies

I downloaded the latest version of Struts 2 to upgrade our current set of jars, and looking at the huge list of jars that come with Struts 2, I want to only include the ones that are truly required.

I had a look at the [Struts 2 dependency tree](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/dependencies.html#Project_Dependency_Graph) and the [Struts 2 compile dependencies](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/dependencies.html#Project_Dependencies_compile), but I'm having trouble understanding what they mean for my application. I don't *think* we use anything in `org.springframework` (doing a workspace-wide search), but is that enough to know whether we can exclude those jars?

Is it as simple as looking at the "optional" column of the compile dependencies table from the 2nd link above? Of the optional ones, how do you know when you need them and when you don't? There are so many....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Struts2 project has a compile dependency on Spring framework. But this doesn't mean that you need a spring framework jars to your project. As you mentioned these dependencies are [*optional*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html). It means they are required if you use some features of Struts2 that depend directly on Spring. You can use Maven to resolve dependencies for your project's `pom.xml`. If you want to view/analize a dependency tree you can use eclipse m2eclipse plugin. Analogous visualization tools available in other IDEs. The same as invoking manually [`mvn dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know Maven had that feature. In my environment, that alone is enough to make me convert my projects to use Maven!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depend on spring framework.

Check [here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-with-artifacts-in-web-inf-lib-and-use-ant-to-build-the-application.html)

> Step 3 - Add Struts 2 Jar Files To Class Path

to see the minimum required libs for a strtus2 project.

Answer (score 0):

[Struts2](https://struts.apache.org) is using the spring framework only for the tests and compiling during build.

Beside this only the [Struts2 Spring plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html) has a dependency to the spring framework.

If you are not using this plugin you should not have any spring dependencies in your project.

Answer (score 0):

struts2 has a dependency on spring framework because of some decent core features.
Dependency injection and AOP are the widely used features of spring framework with struts2.
while struts2 framework is rich in UI and MVC view but these are the components that makes struts2 dependent on spring.
Spring framework's security feature,JDBC,transaction management are the other module that can be used with struts2.

thanks,
Amit Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 does not have any dependency on Spring. However, when you take a look at struts 2 library, it contains Spring related jar. This is done to add additional support to integrate Struts and Spring and to use nice to have features/modules of Spring like DI, AOP, transaction etc. It is completely optional to exclude those jars and to go ahead with conventional Struts framework. Also as there is no incremental development for struts like bringing struts 3 in market. Way to go forward is to integrate struts with Spring.